# recipient_email_user

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I have created a tell a friend form, I am using recipient_email_user to let the user add their friends email address.

In the free form docs it says this data will be posted to the database and be available for viewing in the Freeform CP [Found here](https://solspace.com/software/expressionengine/freeform/docs/form/#tellafriend_form), I have tested it and the user gets the email, however, nothing is stored in the free form entries?

In there example they have a field named friend_email, don't know why that is a required field in the form when there is not an input with that name?

Do i have to create a field called recipient_email_user in order to store it? or should it store automatically to the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is considered a special form by Freeform, so it will work while it is not technically a field that exists. If you wish to store the email address in a regular Freeform field so you can view it later, then you will need to create a Freeform field with the short name of **recipient_email_user**. :)

You're right about the documentation saying it does this automatically. It doesn't, and I will have the documentation updated. :)